# Error while adding firebase-core:16.0.7 and firebase-messaging:17.4.0

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to add Firebase to my project but the problem is I am getting run time error during the project build.[image: Build.gradle(App)[![Build.gradle(App)])][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp4OI.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp4OI.png)

Comment: What is the error? And please also add to your quetion the content of your both `build.gradle` files.

Comment: Post error and put the `build.gradle` file code in question

Comment: I am trying to run gradle->build->assemble and iam getting com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

Answer (score 0):

Error resolved , i removed the jar file from libs folder which was related to GoogleAnalytics which was creating a problem of same classes . so i removed it from gradle